# Primal and dual warm-starts JuMP error message

Tags: optimization, julia, julia-jump, ipopt

I am currently using JuMP to solve an optimisation problem. Based on this;
[Primal and dual warm-starts](https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/conic/start_values/#Primal-and-dual-warm-starts)
it should be possible to initialize the primal and dual variables with the variables from the previous optimisation using the function `set_optimal_start_values(model::Model)`. I added the function to my file, but I get this error message whenever I try to use it;

```
Exception has occurred: 
MathOptInterface.UnsupportedAttribute{MathOptInterface.ConstraintPrimalStart}: 
Attribute MathOptInterface.ConstraintPrimalStart() is not supported by the model.
```

I don't understand the error. It whould be nice if someone had experienced the same problem.
Yes, I have added

```
"warm_start_init_point" => "yes"
```

to my JuMP model

Comment: I have not used this feature, but perhaps you just need a warm startup for the solver and than in almost all cases it is enough to use `JuMP.set_start_value` on all decision variables and then run `optimize!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that Ipopt does not support setting a primal start for the constraints.

You should use

```
julia> using JuMP, Ipopt

julia> function set_optimal_start_values(model::Model)
           # Store a mapping of the variable primal solution
           variable_primal = Dict(x => value(x) for x in all_variables(model))
           # In the following, we loop through every constraint and store a mapping
           # from the constraint index to a tuple containing the primal and dual
           # solutions.
           constraint_solution = Dict()
           nlp_dual_start = nonlinear_dual_start_value(model)
           for (F, S) in list_of_constraint_types(model)
               # We add a try-catch here because some constraint types might not
               # support getting the primal or dual solution.
               try
                   for ci in all_constraints(model, F, S)
                       constraint_solution[ci] = (value(ci), dual(ci))
                   end
               catch
                   @info("Something went wrong getting $F-in-$S. Skipping")
               end
           end
           # Now we can loop through our cached solutions and set the starting values.
           for (x, primal_start) in variable_primal
               set_start_value(x, primal_start)
           end
           for (ci, (primal_start, dual_start)) in constraint_solution
               # set_start_value(ci, primal_start)
               set_dual_start_value(ci, dual_start)
           end
           set_nonlinear_dual_start_value(model, nlp_dual_start)
           return
       end
set_optimal_start_values (generic function with 1 method)

julia> model = Model(Ipopt.Optimizer)
A JuMP Model
Feasibility problem with:
Variables: 0
Model mode: AUTOMATIC
CachingOptimizer state: EMPTY_OPTIMIZER
Solver name: Ipopt

julia> @variable(model, x >= 0)
x

julia> @NLconstraint(model, x^2 <= 1)
x ^ 2.0 - 1.0 ≤ 0

julia> @objective(model, Max, x)
x

julia> optimize!(model)
This is Ipopt version 3.14.4, running with linear solver MUMPS 5.4.1.

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:        0
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        1
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:        1

Total number of variables............................:        1
                     variables with only lower bounds:        1
                variables with lower and upper bounds:        0
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:        0
Total number of inequality constraints...............:        1
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        1

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0  9.9999900e-03 0.00e+00 1.98e+00  -1.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0
   1  1.1773946e-01 0.00e+00 9.86e-01  -1.0 1.08e-01    -  5.58e-01 1.00e+00f  1
   2  3.7890821e+00 1.34e+01 2.47e+00  -1.7 3.67e+00    -  6.52e-02 1.00e+00f  1
   3  2.0163545e+00 3.07e+00 3.94e-01  -1.7 1.77e+00    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   4  1.2438830e+00 5.47e-01 5.70e-02  -1.7 7.72e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   5  1.0080550e+00 1.62e-02 4.63e-02  -1.7 2.36e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   6  9.9794206e-01 0.00e+00 4.09e-04  -2.5 3.52e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   7  9.9984294e-01 0.00e+00 8.28e-06  -3.8 3.90e-03    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   8  9.9999813e-01 0.00e+00 4.51e-08  -5.7 3.14e-04    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   9  1.0000000e+00 0.00e+00 6.87e-12  -8.6 3.78e-06    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1

Number of Iterations....: 9

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:  -1.0000000024889628e+00    1.0000000024889628e+00
Dual infeasibility......:   6.8741856104894100e-12    6.8741856104894100e-12
Constraint violation....:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Variable bound violation:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Complementarity.........:   2.5127966495526885e-09    2.5127966495526885e-09
Overall NLP error.......:   2.5127966495526885e-09    2.5127966495526885e-09


Number of objective function evaluations             = 10
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 10
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 0
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 10
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 0
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 10
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 9
Total seconds in IPOPT                               = 0.004

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.

julia> set_optimal_start_values(model)

julia> optimize!(model)
This is Ipopt version 3.14.4, running with linear solver MUMPS 5.4.1.

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:        0
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        1
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:        1

Total number of variables............................:        1
                     variables with only lower bounds:        1
                variables with lower and upper bounds:        0
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:        0
Total number of inequality constraints...............:        1
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        1

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0  1.0000000e+00 0.00e+00 1.99e-09  -1.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0
   1  9.8764269e-01 0.00e+00 1.17e-02  -1.7 1.47e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   2  9.9675597e-01 0.00e+00 4.71e-04  -2.5 1.82e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   3  9.9983859e-01 0.00e+00 1.56e-05  -3.8 6.23e-03    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   4  9.9999813e-01 0.00e+00 4.55e-08  -5.7 3.29e-04    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1
   5  1.0000000e+00 0.00e+00 6.88e-12  -8.6 3.78e-06    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00h  1

Number of Iterations....: 5

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:  -1.0000000024889595e+00    1.0000000024889595e+00
Dual infeasibility......:   6.8763058686346261e-12    6.8763058686346261e-12
Constraint violation....:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Variable bound violation:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Complementarity.........:   2.5128010673512823e-09    2.5128010673512823e-09
Overall NLP error.......:   2.5128010673512823e-09    2.5128010673512823e-09


Number of objective function evaluations             = 6
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 6
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 0
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 6
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 0
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 6
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 5
Total seconds in IPOPT                               = 0.005

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
```

See https://discourse.julialang.org/t/jump-model-warm-start-using-ipopt/92660 for an identical question on the JuMP community forum.